# KeyError in .format() python 2.6

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, string-formatting

I try to `string format` `{0}` and `{1}` with the variables `type` and `source` but I get `KeyError`:

```
import json
data = {
        "u_in_record_type": '{0}',
        "u_company_source": '{1}'
    }
data = json.dumps(data)
type="Test"
source="Test"
print(data.format(type, source))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(data.format(type, source))
KeyError: '"u_in_record_type"'
```

Comment: and what would you expect of your code?

Comment: it doesn't work because `json` adds the enclosing curly braces. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: replace the {0} with type and the {1} with source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a doomed idea to try to apply `str.format` in json dumps, for several reasons, the main one being that the enclosing `{}` of the string dump conflicts/loses the formatting.

I'd suggest to pre-process your dictionary beforehand with named fields:

```
import json

data = {
        "u_in_record_type": '{type}',
        "u_company_source": '{source}'
    }

type="Test"
source="Source"

new_data = {k:v.format(type=type,source=source) for k,v in data.items()}
```

Pre-python 2.7 syntax (dict comprehensions not available yet):

```
new_data = dict((k,v.format(type=type,source=source)) for k,v in data.items())
```

the dictionary comprehension applies the arguments to all the records, which pick the ones that they need. Then you can dump that version of the dictionary.

A dict-based variant (which can be handy when there are a lot of variables) would be:

```
fd = dict(type="Test",source="Source")
new_data = {k:v.format(**fd) for k,v in data.items()}
```

Comment: i tried to string.format without json dumps but then I get Error that a dictionnary cannot be formatted

Comment: yes, you have to rebuild the dictionary applying the format for each key/value pair

Comment: I get error with your code: `  File "test.py", line 11
    new_data = {k:v.format(type=type,source=source) for k,v in data.items()}
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: Oh ok now it works, could you update the dict--based variant for 2.6 too? `new_data = {k:v.format(**fd) for k,v in data.items()}`

Comment: try `dict((k,v.format(**d)) for k,v in data.items())` but I don't have a python 2.6 to check if it works.